# authenticate Gmail in app without SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, api, gmail, sha1

I was creating a app in which app automatically sends an email after certain events. 
I took help from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android . 
In which SHA1 fingerprint is used to create OAuth 2.0.
If more than 1 developers are working in same project using Git, how are we supposed to do that.
Does every developer has to register its own project with their SHA1 fingerprint on developer console or there is a way-around ?

Thanks,
Cisco